# Poac のビルド時に cmake の実行に失敗する

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, clang

c++のパッケージマネージャーであるPoacを使用したいと思い、以下のページを参考にしてインストールを実施しています。

https://doc.poac.pm/en/getting-started/installation.html

シンボルがないと言われているようですが、解決方法がいまいち分からず困っています。
調べてみると、xcodeの配下にmacの標準コマンドツールがあり、そこのclangを使用している？みたいなことが書かれていたのですが、さっぱり分からなかったです。

エラーメッセージが長くて恐縮ですが、何かわかることや解決方法を知っていたら教えてほしいです。
リンクとかあまりよくわかってないです。

以下がエラーメッセージになります。

```
poac (:main) :$ cmake -B build -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 13.1.6.13160021
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Adding Poac dependencies
--   Adding Boost
--     Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.78.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.78.0", minimum required is "1.70.0") found components: system regex
--     Adding Boost - added
--     Boost include directories are ... /usr/local/include
--     Boost library directories are ... /usr/local/lib
--     Boost libraries are ... Boost::system;Boost::regex
--   Adding Boost::ut
--     Downloading CPM.cmake to /Users/ruimac/poac/build/cmake/CPM_0.31.1.cmake
--     CPM: adding package PackageProject.cmake@1.6.0 (v1.6.0)
--     Adding Boost::ut - added
--   Adding fmt
--     Module support is disabled.
--     Version: 8.1.1
--     Build type: Release
--     CXX_STANDARD: 20
--   Adding git2-cpp
--     Adding git2-cpp - added
--   Adding Glob
--     Downloading CPM.cmake to /Users/ruimac/poac/build/cmake/CPM_0.27.2.cmake
--     Adding Glob - added
--   Adding LibArchive
--     The C compiler identification is AppleClang 13.1.6.13160021
--     Detecting C compiler ABI info
--     Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
--     Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
--     Detecting C compile features
--     Detecting C compile features - done
--     Found ZLIB: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd (found version "1.2.11")
--     Found BZip2: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libbz2.tbd (found version "1.0.8")
--     Extended attributes support: Darwin
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_MD5_LIBC
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_MD5_LIBC -- not found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_RMD160_LIBC
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_RMD160_LIBC -- not found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA1_LIBC
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA1_LIBC -- not found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBC
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBC -- not found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBC
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBC -- not found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBC
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBC -- not found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBC2
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBC2 -- not found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBC2
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBC2 -- not found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBC2
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBC2 -- not found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBC3
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBC3 -- not found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBC3
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBC3 -- not found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBC3
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBC3 -- not found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_MD5_LIBSYSTEM
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_MD5_LIBSYSTEM -- found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA1_LIBSYSTEM
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA1_LIBSYSTEM -- found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBSYSTEM
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBSYSTEM -- found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBSYSTEM
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBSYSTEM -- found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBSYSTEM
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBSYSTEM -- found
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_RMD160_LIBMD
--     Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_RMD160_LIBMD -- not found
--     Adding LibArchive - added
--   Adding libgit2
--     Found PkgConfig: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2")
--     Looking for pthread.h
--     Looking for pthread.h - found
--     Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
--     Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
--     Found Threads: TRUE
--     Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIM
--     Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIM - Failed
--     Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIMESPEC
--     Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIMESPEC - Success
--     Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_MTIME_NSEC
--     Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_MTIME_NSEC - Failed
--     Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_NSEC
--     Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_NSEC - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WERROR_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WERROR_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WNO_ERROR_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WNO_ERROR_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WALL_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WALL_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WEXTRA_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WEXTRA_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WDOCUMENTATION_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WDOCUMENTATION_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WNO_DOCUMENTATION_DEPRECATED_SYNC_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WNO_DOCUMENTATION_DEPRECATED_SYNC_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WNO_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WNO_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WSTRICT_ALIASING_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WSTRICT_ALIASING_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WDECLARATION_AFTER_STATEMENT_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WDECLARATION_AFTER_STATEMENT_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WSHIFT_COUNT_OVERFLOW_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WSHIFT_COUNT_OVERFLOW_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WUNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WUNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WUNUSED_FUNCTION_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WUNUSED_FUNCTION_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WINT_CONVERSION_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WINT_CONVERSION_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WC11_EXTENSIONS_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WC11_EXTENSIONS_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WC99_C11_COMPAT_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WC99_C11_COMPAT_SUPPORTED - Failed
--     Performing Test IS_WFORMAT_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WFORMAT_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WFORMAT_SECURITY_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WFORMAT_SECURITY_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Checking prototype qsort_r for GIT_QSORT_R_BSD
--     Checking prototype qsort_r for GIT_QSORT_R_BSD - True
--     Checking prototype qsort_r for GIT_QSORT_R_GNU
--     Checking prototype qsort_r for GIT_QSORT_R_GNU - False
--     Looking for qsort_s
--     Looking for qsort_s - not found
--     Looking for getentropy
--     Looking for getentropy - found
--     Looking for clock_gettime in rt
--     Looking for clock_gettime in rt - not found
--     Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
--     Found mbedTLS:
--       TLS: /usr/local/lib/libmbedtls.dylib
--       X509: /usr/local/lib/libmbedx509.dylib
--       Crypto: /usr/local/lib/libmbedcrypto.dylib
--     Found Security /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework
--     Looking for SSLCreateContext in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework
--     Looking for SSLCreateContext in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework - found
--     Found CoreFoundation /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework
--     http-parser version 2 was not found or disabled; using bundled 3rd-party sources.
--     Performing Test IS_WIMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_1_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WIMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_1_SUPPORTED - Failed
--     Found PCRE: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libpcre.tbd
--     Looking for bcopy
--     Looking for bcopy - found
--     Looking for strtoll
--     Looking for strtoll - found
--     Looking for strtoq
--     Looking for strtoq - found
--     Looking for _strtoi64
--     Looking for _strtoi64 - not found
--     Check size of long long
--     Check size of long long - done
--     Check size of unsigned long long
--     Check size of unsigned long long - done
--     Performing Test IS_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION_SUPPORTED - Success
--     Performing Test IS_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_SUPPORTED
--     Performing Test IS_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_SUPPORTED - Success
--     LIBSSH2 not found. Set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH if it is installed outside of the default search path.
--     Checking for module 'heimdal-gssapi'
--       No package 'heimdal-gssapi' found
--     Could NOT find GSSAPI (missing: GSSAPI_LIBRARIES)
--     Found GSS.framework /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework
--     Looking for iconv_open
--     Looking for iconv_open - not found
--     Found Iconv: -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib -liconv
--     Enabled features:
     * nanoseconds, support nanosecond precision file mtimes and ctimes
     * futimens, futimens support
     * threadsafe, threadsafe support
     * SHA, using CollisionDetection
     * http-parser, http-parser support (bundled)
     * regex, using bundled PCRE
     * zlib, using bundled zlib
     * iconv, iconv encoding conversion support

--     Disabled features:
     * debugpool, debug pool allocator
     * debugalloc, debug strict allocators
     * debugopen, path validation in open
     * HTTPS
     * SSH, SSH transport support
     * ntlmclient, NTLM authentication support for Unix
     * SPNEGO, SPNEGO authentication support

--     Adding libgit2 - added
--   Adding mitama-cpp-result
--     CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX: /usr/local
--     Adding mitama-cpp-result - added
--   Adding ninja
--     IPO / LTO enabled
--     Performing Test flag_no_deprecated
--     Performing Test flag_no_deprecated - Success
--     Performing Test flag_color_diag
--     Performing Test flag_color_diag - Success
CMake Warning at build/_deps/ninja-src/CMakeLists.txt:49 (message):
  re2c was not found; changes to src/*.in.cc will not affect your build.


--     Adding ninja - added
--   Adding OpenSSL
--     Found OpenSSL: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib (found version "3.0.3")
--     Adding OpenSSL - added
--     OpenSSL include directory is ... /usr/local/opt/openssl/include
--     OpenSSL libraries are ... /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib;/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib;dl
--   Adding Spdlog
--     Build spdlog: 1.10.0
--     Build type: Release
--     Adding Spdlog - added
--   Adding structopt
--     Adding structopt - added
--   Adding Toml11
--     Adding Toml11 - added
-- Adding Poac dependencies - all dependencies are added
-- dependencies are ... Boost::system;Boost::regex;fmt::fmt;git2-cpp::git2-cpp;Glob;archive;git2;mitama-cpp-result::mitama-cpp-result;libninja;libninja-re2c;/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib;/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib;dl;spdlog::spdlog;structopt::structopt;toml11::toml11
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/ruimac/poac/build
poac (:main) :$
poac (:main) :$
poac (:main) :$
poac (:main) :$ ls
CMakeLists.txt      README.md       include         poac.lock       tests
CPPLINT.cfg     build           lib         poac.toml
LICENSE         cmake           poac.example.toml   src
poac (:main) :$ cd build/
build (:main) :$ ninja
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[464/533] Linking C static library _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(openssl_dynamic.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(openssl_legacy.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(stransport.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(auth_negotiate.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(auth_ntlm.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(winhttp.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(pcre_string_utils.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(openssl_dynamic.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(openssl_legacy.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(stransport.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(auth_negotiate.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(auth_ntlm.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(winhttp.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a(pcre_string_utils.c.o) has no symbols
[533/533] Linking CXX executable poac
FAILED: poac
: && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -pthread -O3 -flto -mtune=native -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=12.0 -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/poac.dir/src/main.cc.o -o poac -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/ruimac/poac/build/_deps/libarchive-build/libarchive  lib/cmd/libpoac_cmd.a  lib/util/libpoac_util.a  _deps/libgit2-build/libgit2.a  -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib -liconv  _deps/glob-build/libglob.a  lib/core/libpoac_core.a  lib/core/builder/ninja/libpoac_core_builder_ninja.a  /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib  lib/core/builder/compiler/cxx/libpoac_core_builder_compiler_cxx.a  lib/core/builder/compiler/lang/libpoac_core_builder_compiler_lang.a  lib/data/libpoac_data.a  lib/core/resolver/libpoac_core_resolver.a  lib/util/libpoac_util.a  _deps/libarchive-build/libarchive/libarchive.19.dylib  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libbz2.tbd  /usr/local/lib/libb2.dylib  /usr/local/lib/liblz4.dylib  /usr/local/lib/libzstd.dylib  /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib  /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib  -ldl  _deps/spdlog-build/libspdlog.a  lib/util/semver/libpoac_util_semver.a  _deps/fmt-build/libfmt.a && :
duplicate symbol 'mitama::anyhow::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::shared_ptr<mitama::anyhow::error> const&)' in:
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(lev_distance.cc.o)
    lib/core/resolver/libpoac_core_resolver.a(sat.cc.o)
duplicate symbol 'mitama::anyhow::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::shared_ptr<mitama::anyhow::error> const&)' in:
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(lev_distance.cc.o)
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(cfg.cc.o)
duplicate symbol 'mitama::anyhow::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::shared_ptr<mitama::anyhow::error> const&)' in:
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(lev_distance.cc.o)
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(sha256.cc.o)
duplicate symbol 'mitama::anyhow::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::shared_ptr<mitama::anyhow::error> const&)' in:
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(lev_distance.cc.o)
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(archive.cc.o)
duplicate symbol 'mitama::anyhow::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::shared_ptr<mitama::anyhow::error> const&)' in:
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(lev_distance.cc.o)
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(shell.cc.o)
duplicate symbol 'mitama::anyhow::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::shared_ptr<mitama::anyhow::error> const&)' in:
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(lev_distance.cc.o)
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(pretty.cc.o)
duplicate symbol 'mitama::anyhow::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::shared_ptr<mitama::anyhow::error> const&)' in:
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(lev_distance.cc.o)
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(misc.cc.o)
duplicate symbol 'mitama::anyhow::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::shared_ptr<mitama::anyhow::error> const&)' in:
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(lev_distance.cc.o)
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(net.cc.o)
duplicate symbol 'mitama::anyhow::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::shared_ptr<mitama::anyhow::error> const&)' in:
    lib/util/libpoac_util.a(lev_distance.cc.o)
    lib/core/resolver/libpoac_core_resolver.a(resolve.cc.o)
ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

コンパイラ等のバージョン情報を記載します。

```
Cellar () :$ gcc --version
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
build (:main) :$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.23.1
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

OS: macOS 12.0.1 21A559 x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「`openssl`: `3.0.0` or later」が必要と書かれていますが

> ```
> --     Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
> ```

とあるので見つかっていないようです。事前条件を満たしているか見直しましょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通りでした。mac標準のopensslにリンクされていました。`brew install openssl@3` `brew link openssl --force`